# Required Field Validator, displaying on initial page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have a simple textbox with a required field validation control attached to end and then being displayed in a validation summary at that bottom of the page.  Everything works great on it but the validation seems to fire on the page's initial load which obviously sets off the required validation and displays the error message.

How do I set this control to only validate after the form has been submitted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have code in your page load like this:

```
if (!Page.IsValid) { }
```

What you really want is this:

```
if (Page.IsPostBack && !Page.IsValid) { }
```

Comment: Good catch, Joel! That's most probably the reason.

Comment: I don't have this in page load but I have the same problem

Comment: i have a problem that one ever i click on gridview validation occur and display error how do i stop it??