# Required Field Validator always shows the error message

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have this code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rvFirstName" runat="server" 
 ErrorMessage="Enter First Name" 
ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtFirstName" 
SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

The problem is that the error message shows every time the page loads not only after the submit button has been clicked. I want it to show it only if the user tries click the "Next"(submit) button (how it should work).

If this is relevant: The code above is placed in a UserControl which is included in another UserControl(the "Next" button is here) which is then included in a View of a MultiView.

Any ideas

Comment: Just to clarify does it happens when first time page loads?? and is there any control in your page that causes post back ?

Answer (score 1):

use causeValidation to false on other buttons.

and display to dynamic.

`Display="Dynamic"` on require filed validator

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rvFirstName" runat="server" Display="Dynamic"
     ErrorMessage="Enter First Name" ForeColor="Red" 
     ControlToValidate="txtFirstName" SetFocusOnError="True">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: I do not have problem with any of the Buttons. The error message shows when the page loads

Comment: Or you could use ValidationGroup for the relevant controls (including the button)

Comment: Tried all the things you said. Nothing changes

Answer (score 1):

The best way is set ValidationGroup on Button and RequiredFieldValidator.

Answer (score 0):

please take a look on references below, is it you have something like Page.Isvalid in your page?

References : [Required Field Validator, displaying on initial page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666745/required-field-validator-displaying-on-initial-page-load)

Comment: No I check for Page.IsValid on the click event of the Submit button not on the page load, and I don't check for it anywhere else

Comment: can u post your page load event?

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" 
        ShowMessageBox="True" DisplayMode="BulletList" 
        HeaderText="Validation issues" ShowSummary="False" ValidationGroup="Validation"/>


<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rvFirstName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter First Name" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtFirstName" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="Validation"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Add the above code and modify your `Required Field Validator`

Comment: So your suggestion is to use `ValidationGroups`? I assume that's a problem since the ValidationSummary  is in the page, the button is in a usercontrol and the `TextBox + RequiredFieldValidator` are in a different usercontrol.

Answer (score 0):

Set 'ValidationGroup' for RequiredFieldValidator and the Next button

Comment: The validator and the button are in different files

Answer (score 0):

> Remove the *SetFocusOnError="True"* and add  ***display="Dynamic"*** instead of  *SetFocusOnError="True"* in your *requiredfieldvalidation* and set ***casevalidtion="false"*** in your page.

Comment: I did that, nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

1. 01.If you want to display message in page load. protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           if (!Page.IsPostBack)
           {
               Page.Validate();
           }
       }

   1. Display="Dynamic"